# Number of RAM sticks

Tags: memory, memorystick

I know this question has been posted a lot, but I can't find a satisfying answer anywhere on the Internet.

Is there an advantage to adding 2 `4GB` sticks of RAM to a machine, rather than just adding a single `8GB` stick of RAM?

How does a single stick of RAM affect speed, performance, temperatures and power consumption differently than using two sticks of RAM?

Comment: They are exactly the same in terms of speed, performance, temperatures and power consumption.

Comment: I've heard that 2x4GB is faster (although too small to cont) as well as other difference regarding that I've mentioned

Comment: Where did you hear this? DDR3 is DDR3 the speed diferences would be in connected to the actual frequency differences in the memory. 2x4GB 3000mhz is exactly the same as a single 8GB 3000mhz module.

Comment: @Ramhound Depends on the motherboard configuration. Assuming it doesn't take advantage of Double Channel like technology, 2x4GB memory sticks may be marginally slower than a single one. But it would be too low to tell.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - I assume in this case Double Channel is disabled for comparision ( Apples to Apples )

Comment: @Ramhound OP probably wants to find out which one will give him better performance. If you're choosing between two CPUs you don't underclock the faster one first - same here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So 2x4GB vs 1X8GB.

Assuming both 4GB and 8GB DIMMs have identical specs except for size:

- Iff (and only if) your motherboard supports dual channel, triple channel or quad channel memory access you may see up to 5% speed gains. This very much varies per application.
- 2 DIMMs use two sockets.
- If each 4GB DIMM uses as much power as a 8GB DIMM it would use twice the power (mostly in the order of a few Watts though).

Comment: So all in all using 2 stick might give a bit of performance (mostly ignorable) if the motherboard supports multichannel at the cost of extra power consumption but lower temperatures per stick?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that there could be minor differences in terms of speed, performance, temperatures and power consumption, but these are only relevant to research scientists specifically studying those differences.

Comment: Yes, **asuming** the 8GB stick draws as much power as a **single** 4GB stick. This will not be true unless uses the the number of [bigger] memory chips. In practise I expect the 8GB DIMM to draw a bit more, evening out power usage. Alsop, power usage of DIMMs is small, around 2 Watt per DIMM.